# How can I enable the Flutter Run/Debug toolbar in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

How to enable the above toolkit in VS Code? I have already installed Flutter and Dart extensions, but this isn't appearing. I dont even know it's proper name so Google isn't being of any help. I recently switched from Android Studio to VS Code because of some reasons, and so need help here, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I have figured it out,
**Goto** Run >> **choose** Run without debugging >> and so now you have it.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open *Settings -> and type "Toolbar location"* -> set to  "Floating"

[image]

---

Also note, if you aren't actually running on a device or in debug mode, this bar won't appear

Comment: done, thanks, how to enlarge its size?

Comment: @ElleBishop I'm not sure. Consider closing this question by marking it as accepted and ask a _new_ question on StackOverflow